# Cleaning laptop keyboard using antibacterial wet wipes

Tags: laptop, keyboard, cleaning

I recently ate a meal beside my lenovo laptop. I accidentally spilled some of the food. My keyboard now contained some grease and oil. Having no idea what to do, I used a type of face-cleaning/antibacterial wet wipes to clean the keyboard (particularly
http://www.amazon.in/Origami-So-Soft-Wet-Wipes/dp/B00W1SO7J4
). It is the only cloth I could fined at that time. The keys dried fairly quickly and seemed to work fine. However, through research I found out that in order to really clean laptop keyboards, some sort of alcohol wet wipe should be used. I am concerned that through my recent actions, I have unknowingly destroyed some parts of my keyboard.

My question is: Is using antibacterial wet wipes acceptable in cleanning laptop keyboards? I couldn't find any information regarding this. And although the keyboard keys have dried and is working fine, should I be worried about the consequences of using the wet wipes or I should be satisfied now all is working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, the chances of your keyboard being damaged form wet wipes (generally anything slightly wet and not soaking) is pretty low.

Just to be safe tho, only use anything wet when necessary (like it was now with oil and grease). I personally use a small microfiber cloth for both the screen and the keyboard/trackpad.